# Python PDF Scraping

Tags: python, pdf-scraping

### Task:

PDF which is a bank statement,contains columns i.e (Date,Description,Deposits,Withdrawals,Balance) parsing the columns with their respective fields and export that data in CSV format.[PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-ZP0tBYm-UDepkblTtc_OHsO3KnCjTRK/view?usp=sharing).

### My code:

```
import pdftotext
import re
import csv

# open PDF file
with open('test.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_file:
pdf = pdftotext.PDF(pdf_file)

# extract tabular text
lines = pdf[2].split('\n')[4:]
# CSV table
table = []

# loop over lines in table
for line in lines:
# replace trailing spaces with comas
row = re.sub('   ', ',', line)

# reducing the number of comas to one
row = [cols.strip() for cols in re.sub(',+', ',', row).split(',')]

# handling missed separators
row = ','.join(row).replace('  ', ',').split(',')

# append row to table
table.append(row)

print(table)

# write CSV output
with open('test.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
writer.writerows(table)
```

### Problem:

I am not getting the desired output i.e half of the description is showing under the date table.I am attaching the csv for further ref [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FhbDRXuJAHzSvdEGCQtQ7XDBHekbB6U6/view?usp=sharing).

### Desired Output:

E.g

['04/02','CHRYSLER CAPITAL PAYMENT 0023582513','$469.88-','$51.15']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Example of output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EhjCOVVn-os-lOWmwz0c5H7Eg0vNRJUm/view?usp=sharing)

you can use pdfplumber library its quite useful and i get this output just under five minutes it needs playing with table parameters

```
import pandas as pd
import pdfplumber
pdf = pdfplumber.open(r'C:\Users\Erkin\Downloads\test.pdf')
df = pd.DataFrame()
table_settings={"vertical_strategy": "text", 
    "horizontal_strategy": "lines","intersection_y_tolerance": 8}
df = pd.DataFrame(pdf.pages[3].extract_table(table_settings))
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Erkin\Downloads\test.csv')
```